# Enabling the submit button, when a user makes the first letter capital

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there an easier or simpler way to enable the submit button, when the user makes the first letter of a word capital? (I don't want the user to submit lower case words)

```
def enable_sumbit_button(*event):

    self.uppercase_letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',  'H', 'I','J', 
    'K','L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    self.user_message = self.entry_box.get()
    self.send_button.configure(state='disabled')

    if self.user_message[0] in self.uppercase_letters:
        self.send_button.configure(state='normal')

self.send_button = Button(self.main_window,text="SEND", command=print_user_message, state='disabled')
self.send_button.place(x=410, y=215, width=50, height=28)
self.main_window.bind("Entry","<FocusOut>", enable_sumbit_button)
self.user_input.trace('w', enable_sumbit_button)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python strings have a method isupper() that tests for upper case.  Also your string self.user_message is probably not guaranteed to have any elements (if the user backspaces over the only character in the field).  In that case you get an exception when you try to access [0].  So you should check for a non-empty string first before you check the case of the first character.

```
def enable_sumbit_button(*event):

    self.user_message = self.entry_box.get()
    self.send_button.configure(state='disabled')

    if self.user_message and self.user_message[0].isupper():
        self.send_button.configure(state='normal')
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier alternative would be to force the content of the Entry widget to uppercase, as soon as it looses the focus (or when user validates by pressing the `Enter` key), so there is no more need to disable the submit button:

```
def convert_uppercase(*event):
    self.entry_box.set(self.entry_box.get().upper())
```

and bind the `<FocusOut>` event as you did:

```
self.main_window.bind("Entry","<FocusOut>", convert_uppercase)
```

You may even totally remove the `convert_uppercase` function and perform the corresponding job into the callback function of your submit button.

Comment: Thar converts the whole string to upper case, not just the first character.

Comment: The OP says "I don't want the user to submit lower case words", so I guess he only wants upper case words. If you really need upper case for first char and lower case for the others, the builtin `capitalize()` method for strings does the job. Anyway disabling a submit button without explanation is not a good choice for intuitive user XP, so it is better to point out standard alternatives...

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable interpretation of the question and a good point about the capitablize() method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `isupper` method of strings.

```py
if self.user_message[0].isupper():
   ...
```